# How do you disable readonly attribute in Textbox? VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having a problem disabling the TextBox.ReadOnly attribute.
Here is my code.

```
If (ListView1.EditItem IsNot item) Then
Else
     If User.Identity.Name = "shinya" Then
           Dim jobidtb = CType(item.FindControl("JobTicketIDTextBox"), TextBox)
           jobidtb.Attributes.Remove("readonly")
     End If
End If
```

I have also tried

```
jobidtb.ReadOnly = False
```

but It's not working. I have placed the code in ListView1_DataBound event.

What am I missing here?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to remove the attribute? Just don't use it and you're all set. Am I missing something?

Comment: When/where is the readonly attribute being set in the first place?  In the aspx page or in codebehind?  I know that setting .ReadOnly true and/or false works so perhaps it's being reset to true later in the code?  Have you stepped through a page load line-by-line?

Comment: I would like to disable it only for specific user so that only the user can edit.

Comment: nycdan- is it initially set it in aspx page. I will try removing it from aspx and try...

Comment: Could you be doing a postback after you set it false that resets it?

Comment: I have removed it from aspx and did opposite thing.   jobidtb.ReadOnly = True and it doesn't work. So something is going on other than setting the value. The textbox is in Edititemtemplate.

Comment: Start with basics.  Set a breakpoint on that line and see if you ever execute it.  Let's prove that and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a data bound control, you would need to enable editing of your data.

Comment: Here is textbox. It is inside EditItemTemplate <asp:TextBox ID="JobTicketIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("JobTicketID") %>' ReadOnly="true" />

Answer (score 0):

Read only:

```
Dim jobidtb = CType(item.FindControl("JobTicketIDTextBox"), TextBox) 
jobidtb.ReadOnly = User.Identity.Name.ToLower() != "shinya"
```

Enabled:

```
Dim jobidtb = CType(item.FindControl("JobTicketIDTextBox"), TextBox) 
jobidtb.Enabled = User.Identity.Name.ToLower() = "shinya"
```

Comment: Do I have to place this in specific event? I placed in ListView_DataBound but it's all editable for everyone.

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing `ReadOnly` with `Enabled`? With `ReadOnly` it will still look editable, whereas with `Enabled` set to false it will look greyed out.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me. When you disable editing for a field, do you want it to look greyed out?

Comment: ah sorry. I don't mind the appearance as long as it is not editable and functions the same.

Comment: I think I figured out your problem. The logic was backwards. See edited answer.